# Change output results in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, replace, output

I want to get all user ID's with a specific token assigned.

It looks like this now when I run my script..

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object vasco-LinkUserToDPToken, displayname 

#Output#

vasco-LinkUserToDPToken Displayname

{CN=VES0423061,OU=br... User X           
{}                      User X                
{}                      User X           
{CN=0067511310,OU=br... User X                
{CN=0067077717,OU=br... User X 


Example of a full vasco-LinkUserToDPToken : 
{CN=VES0976944,OU=Internal Users,DC=mgm,DC=agf,DC=be}
```

the thing is I only want to filter VES + it should be shown like this (not containing empty strings or tokens that are not starting with VES):

```
VES0423061  User X
```

Comment: *"I only want to filter VES"* - ...then why did you do `-Filter *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your property 'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken' is a multivalued property type (string array) of which you need to extract the DN inside.

You could try:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "vasco-LinkUserToDPToken -like 'CN=VES*'" -Properties 'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken', DisplayName | 
Select-Object @{Name = 'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken'; Expression = {
    ($_.'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken' | Where-Object {$_ -match '^CN=VES.*'}) -replace '.*(VES[^,]+).*', '$1'}
}, DisplayName
```

P.S. It is always a bad idea to use `-Properties *` is what you are after is just two properties. Using `*` forces to pull down ALL properties which is a waste of time

---

If the `-Filter` doesn't work on this custom property, you can always use a Where-Object clause afterwards like:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties 'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken', DisplayName | 
Where-Object { $_.'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken' -like 'CN=VES*' } |
Select-Object @{Name = 'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken'; Expression = {
    ($_.'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken' | Where-Object {$_ -match '^CN=VES.*'}) -replace '.*(VES[^,]+).*', '$1'}
}, DisplayName
```

Comment: hmm now I'm getting no output at all.

Comment: This  `It is always a bad idea to use -Properties *`

Comment: @Theo `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties vasco-LinkUserToDPToken, displayname | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.vasco-LinkUserToDPToken -like "{CN=VES*"} | Select-Object @{Name = 'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken'; Expression = {
    ($_.'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken' | Where-Object {$_ -match '^{CN=VES.*'})[0] -replace '.*(VES[^,]+).*', '$1'}
}, DisplayName`

Comment: @Toon You may have to single-quote the propertyname in the filter because of the hyphen in there like `-Filter "'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken' -like 'CN=VES*'"`

Comment: I think the problem is specifically where the `$_ -match '^CN=VES*'` is. The reason being that the returned string **will** include the `{` and using `-match` will need to know that.

Comment: @danijeljw-RPC PowerShell shows **arrays** in curly brackets, that's why I started with _multivalued property type_. Since this is a non-standard property, only the OP would know whether this attribute is defined as string or multi-string in the schema. If it is indeed defined as a single string, then it seems **very** unlikely it would be embedded in `{}`, even for those that are not set. Therefore, I don't think the opening `{` is in fact part of the DN inside..

Comment: At line:1 char:109
+ ... name | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.vasco-LinkUserToDPToken -like " ...
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-LinkUserToDPToken' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:128
+ ...  Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.vasco-LinkUserToDPToken -like "{CN=VE ...
+                                                             ~~~~~
Unexpected token '-like' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Getting this a result..

Comment: Getting still the same message when I changed it. ..

Comment: @Theo after your correction I get this result:

Comment: Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: ''vasco-LinkUserToDPToken' -like 'CN=VES*'' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter "'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken' -like 'CN=VES*'" -Prope ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: @Toon We should not flood this with comments.. I added an alternative in my answer.

Comment: @ Theo thanks, now I'm seeing only 'C' as vasco-LinkUserToDPToken

Comment: @Toon Please show us what you get with `(Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties 'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken' | Select-Object 'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken').GetType()`

Comment: IsPublic = True | ISerial = True | Name= Object [] | Basetype = System.Array |

Comment: @Theo I think also it has to do something with $_ -match '^CN=VES*'

Comment: @Toon @Toon OK, it should be either without the [0] due to PowerShell's automatic array unravelling, or ($_.'vasco-LinkUserToDPToken' | Where-Object {$_ -like 'CN=VES.*'}) -replace '.*(VES[^,]+).*', '$1'. Since I used `-match`, there should have been a dot in front of the `*`